# Why has my Android SQLite DB gone corrupt all of a sudden?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

All of a sudden, it seems the database that my application is using has gone corrupt.
I didn't change the structure of the database, but I did re-deploy the app several times on my device today.

It is throwing the following exception.

```
E/Database(14281): CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed err=26 ..
E/Database(14281): Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
E/Database(14281): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not  a database
E/Database(14281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native  Method)
E/Database(14281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1848)
E/Database(14281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1798)
E/Database(14281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:798)
E/Database(14281):  at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:857)
E/Database(14281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:850)
E/Database(14281):  at android.app.ApplicationContext.openOrCreateDatabase(ApplicationContext.java:539)
E/Database(14281):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:193)
E/Database(14281):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
E/Database(14281):  at com.ecs.android.gps.storage.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:75)
```

The database is initialized using the SQLLiteOpenHelper class.

```
public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS location_history");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

- I'm basically opening/closing both
  the database and cursors on each
  operation.
- Some articles indicate
  this being the way to go, but for an
  android app, wouldn't make more sense
  to keep the database connection open
  all the time ?
- I can imagine it
  taking a lot more resources to
  open/close it each time.
- There are multiple Activities and Services that
  access the database.  (potentially at the same time)
- I never saw an exception in the logs

Any idea what could have caused this, how to restore from it, and how to prevent this in the future ?
I have the impression the exception is coming due to some concurrency issues (multiple threads trying to open/close or read/write to the database). I don't know to what degree an SQLite database is as robust as a normal database (mysql - oracle) when it comes to multi-threaded access, locking, .....

Comment: Have you looked at using a data provider for sharing your data across multiple actuvites?

Comment: It is on my TO-DO list, and from what I understand, it could be an option as it does a lot of the plumbing for you, however, I only have 1 table that I read from and write to. I also have no intention of exposing the data to other apps. I just want to know how it gets corrupted, and how I can avoid it (by still using the std SQLiteDatabase and SQLiteOpenHelper classes)

Comment: Unless you've fixed it already, i would further investigate rosstheboss's answer. You mentioned that you had services and activities accessing the database. Given two activities are never really active at the same time you could assume that there safe(r). However the service you mentioned would presumably be running at the same time as an Activity. I'm no expert at java, but i would imagine there are some methods that help lock/check for locks on the database. I.e. is already open, or lock/unlock the database. This would allow you to avoid conflicts, and at the least capture errors.

Comment: just had the same error but with my google contacts Content provider database. Deleted the contacts data and it fixed it. As suggested i would imagine that the issue is with simulataneous access to your data base corrupting it on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly left the Database in an illegal state somehow, although that normally gets flagged and everything carries on fine.

Comment: I'm basically opening/closing the database and cursors on each operation. There are multiple Activities and Services that access the database. However, I never saw an exception in the logs.

Comment: The big problem here is there's no easy way to recover from this. You basically need to uninstall the application (causing it to delete the database) and re-install to deblock the situation.

Comment: You could try. Goto sdk tools folder and run the shell tool adb I think. Then use sqlite3 to explore tables. If that doesn't work you might be able to copy from here to your local machine a recover it with other tools.

Comment: This is an app that will be installed on multiple phones, so manual fixing this is not an option. The db file should never get corrupt (providing the app is running normally and is not constantly getting killed by a taskmanager or something)

Comment: Rereading your initial posting I still can't really give a concrete answer as to why you're getting this 'corruption'. It might be best to try accessing all of your DB calls through a thread safe queue if you think it could be a threading issue. I always tend to open and close a database per operation, it doesn't seem to add that much overhead and helps to ensure it's always left in a good state.

Answer (score 0):

Ae sql lite DB files not in a text readable format? Couldn't you parse the DB file to reconstruct it? Also the locale property, isn't that set on the metadata table that android celreates for you. If so there might be the off chamnce that dropping that table a creating it manually may recover your DB.

Comment: Implementing logic to reconstruct the DB file is something I don't really feel like implementing here :) The android_metadata is indeed created automatically, however, judging from the stack trace, my feeling is that Android already decided that the DB has gone corrupt, and at that point, it deletes the database and re-creates it (I think this is standard Android SQLite behavior). It's during that re-creation that it fails. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong that leads up to the corruption.

Comment: So you can repeat the problem? Each time you've reinstalled the app.

Comment: The re-creation mentioned in the comment doesn't refer to the initial creation of the DB (when installing the app), but rather the re-creation that occurs when Android detects a corrupt db file. It's very hard to reproduce ... I can have the app running for days and all of a sudden it pops up. Next time it can popup after a couple of hours.